# User Control - Custom Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, properties

I have developed a User Control in Visual Studio (WinForms C#) and have a question.

I need the user of my User Control to be able to change certain string values and I would like them to be able to add the user control to their Form and click on it to bring up the Properties Pane where my User Control's custom properties will be displayed.

How can I have my own custom properties for my user control? For example:

My user control contains a TextBox, and I would like the user to be able to change the value of that TextBox via a property named "Text" or "Value" in the properties at Design-Time.

Comment: See Article here -- [Creating Custom Controls in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f5a10c/creating-custom-controls-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: How will your control CONTAINS TextBox control ? Using class inheritance or only a container ? Can you give some codes as Custom user control class definition ?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You do this via attributes on the properties, like this:

```
[Description("Test text displayed in the textbox"),Category("Data")] 
public string Text {
  get => myInnerTextBox.Text;
  set => myInnerTextBox.Text = value;
}
```

The category is the heading under which the property will appear in the Visual Studio Properties box.  [Here's a more complete MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx), including a list of categories.

Comment: My VS2010 crashes each time I want to generate the project with this code, either if I include System.ComponentModel or not :&

Comment: This works for most custom properties, but specifically for overriding the `Text` property (or any other properties that require an override, I assume) Hans' answer below is what will work

Comment: how can I set default value to this property?

Answer (score 55):

It is very simple, just add a property:

```
public string Value {
  get { return textBox1.Text; }
  set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Using the Text property is a bit trickier, the UserControl class [intentionally hides](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UserControl.cs,242) it.  You'll need to override the attributes to put it back in working order:

```
[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Bindable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public override string Text {
  get { return textBox1.Text; }
  set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Completely forgot about this one and it was driving me nuts trying to recall.

Comment: This should be the actual accepted answer. `Text` is handled in a special way

Comment: I don't really understand why it gets so many votes either.  The compiler generates a warning for it, presumably most visitors figure out to stick `new` before it.  Which is normally a very bad idea but does work by accident for a UC.

Comment: @HansPassant The only problem I'm facing is that if I use the code the same as you have it (for the `Text` property) and change it in my parent control's properties pane, it doesn't add the code to the `Form.Designer.cs` and therefore has no effect. The designer view updates, but when I start the application, the change isn't there

Comment: Oh, actually after more Googling I just found the solution: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/403782/Making-an-overridden-Text-property-visible-in-the . Specifically for overriding the `Text` property, you should also have the attribute `DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)` for the changes to get saved from the designer

Answer (score 7):

Just add public properties to the user control.

You can add `[Category("MyCategory")]` and `[Description("A property that controls the wossname")]` attributes to make it nicer, but as long as it's a *public* property it should show up in the property panel.