# Menustrip Style Custom Designer in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create a user control and custom designer.  The perfect example of what I am trying to achieve in design time is how the menuStrip allows you to enter the text of the item being added.

This tells me it is possible, but I do not know if they are just drawing a box/cursor and just handling the key events individually or if they are using a textBox control in the designer somehow.

Is there a way to use controls in the designer during design time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081953/user-control-custom-properties

Comment: Thanks for the info Steve, but I was more looking for a way to allow input into a textBox directly at design time and not through the property grid.  I use menuStrip as the example because that is the closest semblance as to what I am trying to achieve.