# C#- Custom Property of Custom Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, custom-controls, custom-properties

I am creating a custom control using c# in windows form application that uses windows media player control. I want to create a property `isPlaying` as a boolean. If its true, the video should play and if its false, it should pause.

In simple words, I have created a new user control and have inserted a windows media player control in it and I have kept its control box out of the control so its not visible. I now want to create a true/false property for it named `isPlaying`and if its true, the video should play and if its false, it should pause.

Comment: Go ahead, you can do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Control - Custom Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081953/user-control-custom-properties)

Comment: But how @SteppingRazor ? This is the first time I am using C# .....

Comment: @styx . That question is asking for string property.....I'm asking for boolean.......

Comment: @tejasgupta then read a tutorial

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something as simple as this ?

```
private bool _isPlaying = false;

public bool Isplaying
{
    get { return _isPlaying; }
    set 
    {
        _isPlaying = value;

        if (_isPlaying)
        {
            // play vid here
        }
        else
        {
           // stop video here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try @guidoG